# Series of if statements are not returning an int value (Java)

Tags: java, if-statement

I want to compare two objects of Manager using three variables, deptNum, firstName and then lastName. I have set up these objects to be compared using a series of if and if-else statements. The error I am receiving is that the valReturn variable may not have been initialized, which I assume means an if statement somewhere along the way is not assigning a value correctly. I'm not sure where I made a mistake.

If there is a more efficient way to set up this comparison, I would be happy to be educated further.

Thank you.

Below is my code:

```
public class ManagerComparator implements Comparator<Manager> {
public int compare(Manager first, Manager second) {
    int valReturn;
    if (first.getDeptNum() < second.getDeptNum())
        valReturn = -1;
    else if (first.getDeptNum() > second.getDeptNum())
        valReturn = 1;
    else if (first.getDeptNum() == second.getDeptNum()) {
        if (first.getFirstName().compareTo(second.getFirstName()) < 0)
            valReturn = -1;
        else if (first.getFirstName().compareTo(second.getFirstName()) > 0)
            valReturn = 1;
        else if (first.getFirstName().compareTo(second.getFirstName()) == 0) {
            if (first.getLastName().compareTo(second.getLastName()) < 0)
                valReturn = -1;
            else if (first.getLastName().compareTo(second.getLastName()) > 0)
                valReturn = 1;
            else if (first.getLastName().compareTo(second.getLastName()) == 0)
                valReturn = 0;
        }
    }
    return valReturn;
  }
}
```

Comment: One Line: `return Comperator.comparing(Manager::getDeptNum).thenComparing(Manager::getFirstName).thenComparing(Manager::getLastName);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would prefer a simple test against `0` with each incremental comparison. Return the result of each compare as you go. Like,

```
public class ManagerComparator implements Comparator<Manager> {
    public int compare(Manager first, Manager second) {
        int r = Integer.compare(first.getDeptNum(), second.getDeptNum());
        if (r != 0) {
            return r;
        }
        r = first.getFirstName().compareTo(second.getFirstName());
        if (r != 0) {
            return r;
        }
        return first.getLastName().compareTo(second.getLastName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The basic problem you are running into is that the compiler cannot determine that your `if ... else if ... else if ...` is exhaustive.

If we look at your last if block it boils down to

```
if (a() < 0)
    valReturn = -1;
else if (a() > 0)
    valReturn = 1;
else if (a() == 0)
    valReturn = 0;
```

It is not feasible for the compiler to understand that `a()` will return the same value three times meaning that exactly one if condition will be met. The same would happen if you stored `a()` inside a temporary variable.

Solution: make the last one an `else` instead of `else if`.

Answer (score 2):

With Java 8, you can avoid all this boilerplate code and simply do:

```
Comparator<Manager> managerComparator = Comparator.comparingInt(Manager::getDeptNum)
          .thenComparing(Manager::getFirstName)
          .thenComparing(Manager::getLastName);
```

It's self-explanatory, basically creates a comparator which does the same thing you're trying to do - compare by dept number, then by first name, then by last name.

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

Answer (score 1):

You're using only `else if`. If you follow your logic you can see that all cases will enter one of the statements. However, the compiler doesn't know that.

Simply changing the last `else if` in these instances to `else should resolve it.

However, the code in Elliot's post would be a cleaner alternative.